# Bootstrap multiselect dropdown does not work inside div having ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to use bootstrap multiselect dropdown for selecting multiple values for parameters . I am using it like -

```
<div ng-repeat="param in parameters">
  <div>{{param.name }} :</div>
  <div ng-show = "param.multipleValues">
    <select ng-model="param.value" id="testMultiSelect" multiple="multiple">
        <option ng-repeat="v in values" value="{{v}}" >{{v}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div ng-show = "!param.multipleValues">
    <input type="text" ng-model="param.value">
  </div>
</div>
```

But , somehow , multiselect is not working inside ng-repeat. If I put it outside of this div having ng-repeat , it works. 
It comes like in image - 
[image]

Comment: this may helps you http://jsfiddle.net/cojahmetov/3DS49/

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This may helps you

```js
 
 var app = angular.module('testApp', [ ]);
 
 
 app.directive('telDropdownmutiple', ['$http', function ($http) {
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: {
             array: '=',
             validate: '@',
             ngModel: '=',
             title: '@',
             checkId: '@',
             ngmaxLength: '@',
             ngminLength: '@',
             lblvalue: '@',
             textboxSize: '@',
             lblSize: '@',
             ngShow: '@',
             textboxtype: '@',
             getString: '@',
             multiple: '@',
         }, 

         template:'<div   id="{{ checkId }}"  > <span>{{ title }}</span>:<select  {{ multiple }}  class="{{className}}"  ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] for a in array"   requireiftrue="{{ validate }}"></div>'+
      '<option style="display: none" value="">{{title}}</option>' +
     '</select> </div>',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

             scope.lblvalue = attrs.lblvalue;
             scope.title = attrs.title;
             scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
             scope.optDescription = attrs.optDescription;
          
         }
     };
 }]);
 
   app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
        
         $scope.SelectMultiple = [
   {Id: 1, Description: "option1"}, 
   {Id: 2, Description: "option2"}, 
   {Id: 3, Description: "option3"}, 
   {Id: 4, Description: "option4"},
   {Id: 5, Description: "option5"},
   {Id: 6, Description: "option6"}, 
   {Id: 7, Description: "option7"}, 
   {Id: 8, Description: "option8"}, 
   {Id: 9, Description: "option9"},
   {Id: 10, Description: "option10"}
   ];
 
   
      
  }]);
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" data-ng-app="testApp">
  
            <!-- Logo -->
    
        <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
   

        <div class="content-wrapper" style=" margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 350px;   overflow-y: auto; " ng-controller="testController">
       <tel-Dropdownmutiple multiple ng-model="registration.multipledropGender"   lblvalue="Gender" array="SelectMultiple" opt-value="Id" opt-description="Description" validate='true' class-Name="form-controlselect select2" ></tel-Dropdownmutiple>
    </div>
 
 
 


</body>
```